# Need help uploading to github

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm facing some issues uploading my website/homework to git. I cloned my teacher's repo and worked on his project as he recommended and as I've done before without any problems. The thing is that when I try to upload it it says that

> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits. (use "git push" to publish your local commits). Nothing to commit, working tree clean

When I try to push it says

> The requested URL returned error: 403

and that I am denied access. It seems that it's trying to push to my teacher's repo even though I try to upload it to mine. I have copied the whole project, created a new repo but I still get the same message. When I try to upload my project by committing to master in GitHub desktop I'm getting a fail message.

Comment: Have you forked the repo and are you pushing to *that* repo? You probably don't have permissions to push to your teacher's repository. If you include a clear list of all the commands you used, it'll be easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi Aurora0001! One of the ways was this: I opened my repository in github desktop and opened it in terminal, wrote git add ., git status to check, git commit -m"my message" and git push. That's the way i was taught in my school.

Comment: When I type git status it says "On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'. nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Comment: You might find it easier to edit your question to put the extra information in; there isn't a lot of room in each comment. Try running `git remote get-url origin`. Is that a repository that you have write access to, or is it your teacher's repository?

Comment: No, I don't have access to it but my teacher told us we could clone it to get the same structure as his project and then work on it. Already tried `git remote get-url origin`.

Comment: You won't be able to push if you don't have write access. Were you told to push your changes back to a fork when you were done? If so, click the 'Fork' button, near the 'Star' option, then follow [these steps](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) to push to your fork.

Comment: No, I want to push my project to my repo. but for some strange reason his repo keeps showing up.

Comment: Is your current repo empty or has it already got contents? If it's already got stuff in you'll probably need to manually merge them after [setting the new remote URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) (use the name `origin`).

Comment: I work on the master and want to add another folder to my repo. Every project/homework is in a folder.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to clone your current projects repo, copy in the files that you've worked on then commit to that so you don't have to change the remote URLs (which is slightly more difficult and error prone).

Comment: Tried that previously but I did it again on my desktop this time. 'Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean' and my teachers repo pops up again even though I cloned mine.

Comment: Was this in a completely fresh directory? It seems strange if your teacher's repo appears in a fresh repo cloned from your own GitHub repo.

Comment: I know, yes, it was fresh, cloned my own on a completely different directory.

Comment: Any chance you could copy the exact output ffrom the command prompt and edit it into the question (see [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_dos_copy.mspx) for how to copy from the prompt)? This seems bizarre and definitely shouldn't happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128485/discussion-between-anna-bannanna-and-aurora0001).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `git clone <your teacher’s URL>`, if you did this, you can not to push the changes to your teacher’s repo because of permission denied. Try to use these steps below:

1. Click the **fork** button on your teacher's repo URL, it will show another page, click **clone or download**, copy the **https address**
2. In your local directory, use `git clone <the https address you copied>`, so you can make changes on the fork repo
3. use `git commit` to commit changes, and use `git push`, then you can push successfully
4. When your teacher log in his GitHub, he will find you work in a pull request.

**Note:** you should use **https** to clone the fork repo, if you use **ssh**, it may has some access rights issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having sounds like your repo is still set up with your teacher's repo as `origin` (the default upstream, in `git`-speak) rather than your own private one.

If you're using the `git` command-line, use

```
git remote set-url origin <url>
```

where `<url>` is the URL for your copy of the repo on the server to set the URL to where it needs to go. If you want to keep the teacher's repo under a new name, you can do:

```
git remote rename origin teacher
git remote add origin <url>
```

This will set your private repo as the default upstream, so when you do `git push` it'll try to push there instead of your teacher's copy.

[Full man page for `git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)